# Kubernetes secrets - error parsing test-secret-tls.yml - could not find expected

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I have the following files from letsencrypt `cert.csr, cert.pem, chain.pem, fullchain.pem, privkey.pem`
and I copied the base64 version of cert.pem and privkey.pem.

`cat cert.pem  | base64` and `cat privkey.pem | base64`

But I get the following error:

`error: error parsing test-secret-tls.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 10: could not find expected ':'`

Also I wonder how the documentation and other articles use one line for the cert and key values while I have a mutliline values.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test-certs-secret
  namespace: test-web-dev
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: VkRBVmtoVlVocEZCbjVPaUd1bFdYaGdwQUEKV0JQb3BUeFQvcDVqamtwVUdRRFhSU2FZc29HSVht
VkRBVmtoVlVocEZCbjVPaUd1bFdYaGdwQUEKV0JQb3BUeFQvcDVqamtwVUdRRFhSU2FZc29HSVht
VkRBVmtoVlVocEZCbjVPaUd1bFdYaGdwQUEKV0JQb3BUeFQvcDVqamtwVUdRRFhSU2FZc29HSVht
  tls.key: VkRBVmtoVlVocEZCbjVPaUd1bFdYaGdwQUEKV0JQb3BUeFQvcDVqamtwVUdRRFhSU2FZc29HSVht
VkRBVmtoVlVocEZCbjVPaUd1bFdYaGdwQUEKV0JQb3BUeFQvcDVqamtwVUdRRFhSU2FZc29HSVht
VkRBVmtoVlVocEZCbjVPaUd1bFdYaGdwQUEKV0JQb3BUeFQvcDVqamtwVUdRRFhSU2FZc29HSVht
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While encoding the cert and private key, you can specify the `-w`(linux) or `-b`(macOS) flag to the `base64` command to encode it in a single line.

You can then use those in your yaml and it should not complain.

For linux:

```
cat cert.pem  | base64 -w0
cat privkey.pem | base64 -w0
```

For macOS:

```
cat cert.pem  | base64 -b0
cat privkey.pem | base64 -b0
```